# Vagrant box with pre installed libraries

Tags: vagrantfile

How to add a vagrant box with pre-installed libraries using 'config-vm.box' in Vagrantfile? for e.g. I want to configure my vm with CentOS 6 + Tomcat 8 + java 8 to be installed, and don't want to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a provisionning technology like packer : [PACKER](https://www.packer.io/)

With this you can configure provisionning with json file and run a script bash file for launch command linux like 'apt-get'

**EDIT :**

OK you can find a lot of Vagrant boxes with this two url :

- [Vagrant Atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search)
- [Vagrant boxes List](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)

With this, you have a lot of boxes available by simple name (with config.vm.box) or URL (with config.vm.box_url)

Also you can find a lot of boxes built by anyone into the community with gitHub (eg : [Personnal Vagrant boxes community](https://github.com/irmantas/symfony2-vagrant)

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it now ;)

Comment: if it's good for you please vote for this response for help others with the same issue in the futur.

Comment: would like to but stackoverflow still does not allow me to vote :( need more reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :shell provisioner, providing commands inline or providing the path to your custom script.

config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "echo Hello, World"

OR

config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script.sh"

where script.sh would contain commands to install the required software packages.

For more information, look  here
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html